# $1+m$ with $m\in (t_1,\ldots, t_n)$ is a unit in $K[[t_1,\ldots,t_n]]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $K$ be a field. Show that any element of the form $1+m$ with $m\in (t_1,\ldots, t_n)$ is a unit in $K[[t_1,\ldots,t_n]]$

I'd say that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nm^n$ is the inverse of $1+m$, and hence $1+m$ is a unit. But I need to show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nm^n=\frac{1}{1+m}$. To do this, I was thinking of using the definition of convergence as given below.

> Let $A=K[[t_1,\ldots,t_n]]$ consider the ideal $(t_1,\ldots, t_n)$ in $A$. Let $\{a_n\}$ be a collection of elements in $A$. We say that $a_n$ converges to $a\in A$ if for all $N>0$ there exists some $M>0$ such that for any $m>M$ we have $a_m-a\in (t_1,\ldots, t_n)^N$.

I considered the coefficients of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nm^n$ as the collection $\{a_n\}$. So I'd say that for large enough $m$, then $(-1)^m-\frac{1}{1+m}\in (t_1,\ldots,t_n)^N$ since $(-1)^m-\frac{1}{1+m}$ is zero in $K[[t_1,\ldots,t_n]]/(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$, since $m$ is in $(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$. Is the valid, and is the approach correct to show that $1+m$ is a unit?

Comment: Do you mean $m$ is a *member* of the list of variabes, or an $n$-tuple ? (confused by your notation)

Comment: @coffeemath I think it's likely that $(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n)$ stands for the ideal generated by the listed elements. Granted, the OP could spell it out for us :-)

Comment: Sorry my bad. $m$ is an element of the ideal $(t_1,\ldots, t_n)$.

Comment: What is $(-1)^m$? I don't understand your reasoning.

Comment: $(-1)^m=a_m$ as in the given definition of convergence (it's a member of the collection $\{a_n\}$)

Comment: Would that be sufficient? I'm in doubt since it's an infinite series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, you just have to compute 
\begin{align}
(1+m)\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^nm^n&=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^nm^n+\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^nm^{n+1}\\
&=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^nm^n+\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^nm^{n+1}\\
&=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^nm^n+\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^{n-1}m^n\\
&=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}[(-1)^n+(-1)^{n-1}]m^n\\
&=1.
\end{align}

Comment: Hmm. I think you do have to pay a little bit of attention to the convergence. After all, an infinite sum usually does not make sense in an arbitrary ring. It is probably clear to you, but since this was given as an exercise I predict that the teacher will pounce on this. Here the sum $\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^nm^n$ makes sense as a formal power series if **and only if** $m$ is an element of the ideal $I=(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Agreed. The point being that $m$ is a linear combination of monomials of degree $\geq 1$, so $m^n$ is a linear combination of monomials of degree $\geq n$. Therefore, only finitely many terms in the sum contribute to the degree $n$ component for any $n$.